# auto update total onkeyup with angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a list of users from a web api which i've supplied the user with a search box to filter to make searching easy.
On the top side of the table too i've provided the total number of users returned by the api.

What i have to do is when the user starts typing and results are being filtered, the total number of displayed should also be updated

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" class="table">
  <tr>
    <td width="6%"><strong>Filter By</strong></td>
    <td width="94%">                <select ng-model="queryBy">
                    <option value="$"></option>
                    <option value="Customer_Name">Name</option>
                    <option value="Address">Adddress</option>
                    <option value="Region">Region</option>
                    <option value="District">District</option>
                </select>   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Search</strong></td>
    <td>      <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" placeholder="Search Customers" ng-model="query[queryBy]"/>
      </div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>


<img src="img/loader.gif" width="100" height="13" border="0" /> 
</div>
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Total Customers: {{users_list.length}}</td>
    </tr>
  <tr class="success">
    <td><strong><a style="color: black; text-decoration: none" href="#/home" ng-click="clikme('Customer_Name')">Customer Name</a></strong></td>
    <td><strong>Phone Number</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Address</strong></td>
    </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="item in users_list | filter: query ">
    <td>{{item.Customer_Name}}</td>
    <td>{{item.Phone_Number}}</td>
    <td>{{item.Address}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
```

JS

```
.controller('app_users_ctrl',function($scope,$http,$location){

    $scope.query = {};
    $scope.queryBy = '$';

    $http.post('http://websource.com/calls/app_users.php').success(function(data){
    $scope.users_list=data
    //console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    $scope.loading=false;
        })

    $scope.clikme= function(field){
    $scope.myvar= order ? '-' + field : '+' + field;
        order=!order;
    }

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo need to use lenght for the filtered result so try this.

change `{{users_list.length}}` for `{{ (users_list | filter: query).length }}`